# How do I automatically cast a value obtained from FieldInfo.GetValue to the correct type?

Tags: c#, reflection, casting

If I have a bunch of instances of `FieldInfo`, and I already know that their `FieldType` is one of the types that can be passed to `BinaryWriter.Write(...)`, how do I automatically pass the field of a given object to the `BinaryWriter.Write(...)` without testing `FieldType` against a set of types and manually casting to the matching type?

E.g. How do I avoid having to do the following:

```
object value = fieldInfo.GetValue(foo);
if (fieldInfo.FieldType == typeof(int))
{
    binaryWriter.Write((int)value);
}
// followed by an `else if` for each other type.
```

**UPDATE:**

Should have said, I'd like to do this targeting .NET 2.0, ideally using nothing that isn't in C# 3.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using C# 4, the simplest approach would be to use dynamic typing and let that sort it out:

```
dynamic value = fieldInfo.GetValue(foo);
binaryWriter.Write(value);
```

That's assuming you always just want to call an overload of `binaryWriter.Write`. Another alternative is to have a dictionary from the type of the value to "what to do with it":

```
static readonly Dictionary<Type, Action<object, BinaryWriter>> Actions = 
    new Dictionary<Type, Action<object, BinaryWriter>>
{
    { typeof(int), (value, writer) => writer.Write((int) value) },
    { typeof(string), (value, writer) => writer.Write((string) value) },
    // etc
};
```

Then:

```
object value = fieldInfo.GetValue(foo);
Actions[value.GetType()](value, binaryWriter);
```

Comment: Sadly I'm not using C# 4. I'm using C# 3.0 targeting .NET 2.0. The dictionary idea is interesting though, thanks.

Comment: Or, better yet, `GetMethods().ToDictionary` with an expression tree.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `Write` using reflection to find the correct overload at runtime rather than compile-time:

```
typeof(BinaryWriter).InvokeMember(
    "Write", 
    BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, 
    null,
    binaryWriter,
    new object[] { value }
);
```

If you're using C# 4, you could also just use `dynamic`:

```
binaryWriter.Write((dynamic)value);
```

Comment: Can you give more detail? Maybe an example or link? Thanks.

Comment: The first. I'm using C# 3.0 targeting .NET 2.0 for my sins.

Comment: Beware that it will be rather slow.  Jon Skeet's dictionary of delegates should be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

the dynamic keyword would work here

```
binaryWriter.Write((dynamic)value);
```

Comment: duplicate and wrong framework, should have pressed return rather than make a cup of tea :)